# Expected a spy, but got Function with using spyOn()

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

Using Angular and Karma/Jasmine

I am getting `ERROR: 'Unhandled Promise rejection:', '<toHaveBeenCalled> : Expected a spy, but got Function.`. But from what I can tell, I am spying on the method `login`. Any idea what is wrong?

````js
    fit('should redirect to login because user is not auth', async() => {
      authState$.next({ isAuthenticated: false });
      spyOn(component, 'login').and.callThrough();
                           
      fixture.whenStable().then(() => {                  
        expect(component.login).toHaveBeenCalled();      
      });                                                
    });  
    ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`expect` expects the spy returned by `spyOn`

```
fit('should redirect to login because user is not auth', async() => {
      authState$.next({ isAuthenticated: false });
      const mySpy = spyOn(component, 'login').and.callThrough();
                           
      fixture.whenStable().then(() => {                  
        expect(mySpy).toHaveBeenCalled();      
      });                                                
    });
```